# Convert sha256 to smaller uint type

Tags: c, hashtable, sha256

I'm implementing a hash table in c and I chose as key the sha256 hash of the file that I need to store. The problem is that I need to convert the key to a reusable index to insert in the hash table. I tought to rehash the key, but this way I would increase the possibility of overlapping values. Is there a way to use this hash as the key to the table?

The sha256 is store as a BYTE[32] or can be converted as a sting

```
void* ht_get(ht* table, const char *key) {
    size_t index = magicfunction(key);

    while (table->entries[index].key != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(key, table->entries[index].key) == 0) {
            // Found key, return value.
            return table->entries[index].value;
        }
        // Key wasn't in this slot, move to next (linear probing).
        index++;
        if (index >= table->capacity) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
 }
```

Comment: If it is 32 bytes, it is 32 bytes—That is unusable as an index, regardless of what type it is, because you simply cannot have enough memory for a table indexed by 32 bytes. You must use a smaller size, and that will increase collisions. You do not need to rehash it, though, you can simply use as many bytes from it as you wish.

Comment: Unless you can allocate a table of size 1e77, you will have to throw away some part of the hash and then deal with the resulting hash collisions.

Comment: Since `sha256` is considered a good random number generator, I would suggest just using the fist 8 bytes or what ever the size of your `size_t` is. And of course don't forget `index %= table->capacity;` afterwards.

Comment: @Cosinus That assumes you don't need resistance to algorithmic complexity attacks. A malicious attacker who can choose the data you need to store can pick all items with the same first N bits for as large a value of N as they're willing to devote resources. Making the first 10 bits collide is not particularly difficult, reducing the effective size of your table to 1/1000th its actual size.

Comment: Do you need to deal with potentially malicious data? That is, are you concerned that an attacker might be able to choose the data you hash such that they cause hash collisions and reduce the effective size of your table? You may need to use a random method of reducing the hash space if you need to resist algorithmic complexity attacks.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: A hash plus a “random” reduction is a hash. It is subject to the same brute-force attack as a hash plus a simplistic reduction.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Do you suggest, salting the uploaded content with an at startup defined random number, before hashing it with `sha256`?

Comment: @Cosinus That would be one way to do it. Another way is to use some randomness in the process of "compressing" the SHA256 hash. You can use something like xxhash to compress a random seed followed by the SHA256 hash. (This is what the XRP Ledger's hash tables due to [defend against algorithmic complexity attacks](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/src/ripple/basics/hardened_hash.h).)

Answer (score 0):

When I need an absolute minimalist hashmap in C, I usually end up doing something like that:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct hmap_entry {
  const char *key;
  /* Or in your case: */
  /* char key[SIZE_OF_SHA256]; */

  void *payload;
};

#define HMAP_ENTRY_CNT 256
struct hmap {
  struct hmap_entry entries[HMAP_ENTRY_CNT];
};

static size_t str_hash(const char *s) {
  size_t hash = 0;
  while(*s) {
    hash = (hash << 7) ^ (size_t)*s++ ^ hash;
  }
  return hash;
}

static struct hmap_entry *hmap_search_entry(struct hmap *map
    , const char *key)
{
  size_t hash = str_hash(key);
  /* Or in your case: */
  /* size_t hash = 0; memcpy(&hash, key, sizeof(key)) */

  hash = hash % HMAP_ENTRY_CNT;

  struct hmap_entry *e = NULL;
  while(1) {
    e = map->entries + hash;

    if(e->key == NULL
        || strcmp(key, e->key) == 0) {
      break;
    }
    /* Or in your case: */
    /* if(e->key == NULL
          || memcmp(key, e->key, SIZE_OF_SHA256) == 0) {
        break;
       }
     */


    hash = (hash + 1) % HMAP_ENTRY_CNT;
  }
  return e;
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
int main()
{
  struct hmap_entry *e;
  struct hmap map = {};

  /* insert foo */
  e = hmap_search_entry(&map, "foo");
  e->key = "foo";
  e->payload = "hello world";

  /* insert bar */
  e = hmap_search_entry(&map, "bar");
  e->key = "bar";
  e->payload = "Something else";

  /* get foo */
  e = hmap_search_entry(&map, "foo");
  if(e->key) {
    printf("Value of \"%s\" is \"%s\"\n", e->key, (const char *)e->payload);
  }
  else {
    printf("Not found!\n");
  }

  /* get bar */
  e = hmap_search_entry(&map, "bar");
  if(e->key) {
    printf("Value of \"%s\" is \"%s\"\n", e->key, (const char *)e->payload);
  }
  else {
    printf("Not found!\n");
  }

  /* get test */
  e = hmap_search_entry(&map, "test");
  if(e->key) {
    printf("Value of \"%s\" is \"%s\"\n", e->key, (const char *)e->payload);
  }
  else {
    printf("Not found!\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```